# Trying to identify a locked up iMac

Tags: imac

I've got an old iMac sitting around, no one remembers the password to log into it so we are trying to erase the hard drive to setup a new OS. First I got to identify the model though. It would be great if someone could help me with that, I attached an image of what is written on the bottom of the iMac.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com) has a fabulous utility on their site to [identify any Mac](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=) from its Serial Number or other identifying marks.

In this case, it looks like you have a [Late 2006 iMac Core2Duo 2.6GHz 24"](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.16-24-inch-specs.html)

[image]

If you don't have the original install disks, then your best bet would be to buy [Snow Leopard](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) directly from Apple. The latest OS the machine can run is Lion 10.7.5, but that is a download only. You'd need 10.6 first.